# Why is my test database is not being truncated before tests are being ran?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, mongoid

I am running tests in cucumber and would like the database to be empty for the tests I am running. I've configured the settings to do this but data exists when I run the tests.  What am I doing wrong?  Also I am using mongoid and am using MongoDB.

features/support/env.rb:

```
require 'cucumber/rails'

Capybara.default_selector = :css
Dir[(Rails.root + "spec/factories/**/*.rb").to_s].each {|factory| require factory}
ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end

Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation

if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  begin
    require 'database_cleaner'
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  rescue LoadError => ignore_if_database_cleaner_not_present
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually cleaning the database at any point. You have Database Cleaner, but aren't calling the clean method.

Try this in env.rb

```
Before do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

After do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```